# pushViewController problem

Tags: iphone, graphics, delegates, quartz-graphics

I create a UIViewController with a button on it.  The button's only job is to create a window for drawing some rectangles.  (I've taken some code from "QuartzDemo" from Apple's example applications.)  Objective C is really giving me fits...

When I try this, nothing happens.

Here's the code for the button:

```
- (IBAction)startButtonAct:(id)sender
{
    QuartzViewController *controller;

    NSLog(@"1");
    controller = [[QuartzViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"Dotsie"];
    controller.quartzViewDelegate = [[[RectDrawing alloc] init] autorelease];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    // [controller release];

}
```

I'm honestly not sure what else anyone needs to see, but here's some of the other stuff:

```
@interface QuartzViewController : UIViewController
{
    QuartzView *quartzView;
    UIBarStyle barStyle;
    UIStatusBarStyle statusStyle;

}


@protocol QuartzViewDelegate;

@interface QuartzView : UIView {

id<QuartzViewDelegate> delegate;

}

@property(assign) id<QuartzViewDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol QuartzViewDelegate<NSObject>

@required

// Draw contents into the given view, using the given context and bounds.
-(void)drawView:(QuartzView*)view inContext:(CGContextRef)context bounds:(CGRect)bounds;

@end
```

Please help -- this is driving me crazy -- I've been fighting with the same basic problem now for a week...

Answer (score 1):

First, the [controller release] line should be there, uncommented. I'm sure you just disabled it for debugging.

If you insert the line:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self navigationController]);
```

In your button action, does it log a valid controller or does it say nil? If it's nil, my guess is that this view controller wasn't properly pushed onto a navigation controller itself.